# A delta method style theorem for this scenario?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, asymptotics

Let $\{Z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent standard normal vectors with dimensions increasing according to the function $d(n).$ Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random vectors with each element $X_n$ also having dimension $d(n)$ and having been obtained from $Z_n$ according to a deterministic process.

I have a result that the maximum of the absolute values of the elements of the vector $\sqrt{n} X_n - Z_n$ goes to $0$ in probability as $n \to \infty.$ Thus, for large $n,$ $\sqrt{n} X_n$ can, in a sense, be approximated by $Z_n.$

I also have a "nice" function $g_n$ (indexing by $n$ only because the dimension of the argument changes) for which it appears (based on simulations) that $g_n(X_n)$ is asymptotically multivariate normal (and likely even diagonal). That is, as $n \to \infty,$ $g_n(X_n)$ looks increasingly like a multivariate normal.

To me, this scenario resembles the setting for the multivariate delta method, except that the dimensions are changing. Is there an analogous approach that might allow me to conclude that, for large $n,$  $g_n(X_n)$ is "close" to being multivariate normal with a covariance matrix depending on the $g_n$?

If not, is there another approach you would recommend for proving something like this?

The set up described seems like a multivariate version of this problem: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044231/delta-method-ish-question?rq=1). If I were able to show that a distance between some suitable transformation $Y_n$ of $g_n(X_n)$ and $X_n$ went to zero (analogous to what they do in the univariate case), then that would tell me that $g_n(X_n)$ can be approximated by independent normals for large $n.$